# Signing AIR Applications

Tags: flash, air, distribution, code-signing

Can I sign my Adobe AIR app with my iOS development certificate? I saw on Adobe's website that a company called `Thawt` is a valid CA. Beneath their name, I saw Apple listed.

Does this mean that I can sign my app with Apple's iOS dev certificate? If so, how?

Comment: it would be pretty interesting if this was possible, since apple's dev program is much cheaper than most certificates from CAs per year.  why not try it?  publish your air app with your iOS.p12 cert and see what the installing dialogue displays when you install it on your system.

Comment: @TDI1978 - I tried. It didn't work. >Could not sign the AIR file.

Unable to build a valid certificate chain for the signer.

Comment: it's been a while since i developed for iPhone, and now that i think about it, i believe your cert is validated by apple when they accept an application you've submitted.  your development key .p12 file should be available in your iTune Connect account, or in your KeyChain application.  something like that.

Comment: just an FYI, to promote Adobe's new InMarket they are offering free 1-year certificates to AIR developers.  but you have to upload your application to InMarket within 30 days of receiving your certificate.  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/inmarket.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a certificate issued from Thawte called "Apple Developer Certificate" or something similar, it should work, theoretically. I've seen that unable to build valid certificate chain error before, even with valid certificates. It is generally caused by you trying to use the base certificate from the issuer without the CA cert bundled. You can fix it by importing the cert to a trusted keychain and then exporting the cert in PKCS format(I believe) while including the CA cert chain. See this site for more details: http://www.alivelearn.net/?p=892

Comment: Yeah, that blogger was using an older version of FF I believe. It's under Tools->Options->Advanced->Encryption in mine. You have to import the cert and then export it with the CA bundled. Your exact menus might be different depending on version/OS so you may have to look around a little bit in options.

Comment: The root certificate found at Thawte is not the one mentioned in your link. Can you send me that certificate? also, the article mentioned exporting keys from menu options that don't exist. What program should I be using? (Edited due to misspelling of word "program")